# UploadCare not able to find DOM element matching selector after I created React Portal

Tags: css, reactjs, dom

I am using UploadCare in a modal that is now being rendered through a Portal (from React 16). UploadCare was working fine in the modal until I created a React portal and then the error below occurred:

```
Error: No DOM elements found matching selector
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
UploadCare.componentDidMount
src/components/UploadCare.js:8
   5 | class UploadCare extends Component {
   6 |   componentDidMount() {
   7 |     const { onChange } = this.props;
>  8 |     const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${this.id}`);
```

I am creating my portal like this: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd

UploadCare requires a DOM selector, in which I'm using one called id. Code below:

```
class UploadCare extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${id}`);

    if (onChange && typeof onChange === "function") {
      widget.onChange(file => {
        if (file) {
          file.done(info => onChange(info.cdnUrl)).fail(() => onChange(null));
        } else {
          onChange(null);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        type="hidden"
        name={name}
        id={id}
        data-public-key={process.env.REACT_UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

I have fixed the error by using a ref, but I don't understand why the error occurred. Can someone explain to me what a portal did to affect the DOM and my CSS selector and why it requires me to now use a ref to find the DOM element?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ref is right way. [Official documentation of React](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom#when-to-use-refs) suggests to use ref for integration with third-party DOM libraries (like Uploadcare Widget). So, this right code:

```
class UploadCare extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const widget = uploadcare.Widget(this.uploader);

    if (onChange && typeof onChange === "function") {
      widget.onChange(file => {
        if (file) {
          file.done(info => onChange(info.cdnUrl)).fail(() => onChange(null));
        } else {
          onChange(null);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { id, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <input
        type="hidden"
        ref={input => this.uploader = input}
        name={name}
        id={id}
        data-public-key={process.env.REACT_UPLOADCARE_PUBLIC_KEY}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

What about `id`? So, in your code you use `${id}` in one place

```
    const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${id}`);
```

and `${this.id}` in another place

```
>  8 |     const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${this.id}`);
```

But, in scope of `componentDidMount` these variables are undefined.

Try to use props

```
    const { onChange, id } = this.props;
    const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${id}`);
```

or

```
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    const widget = uploadcare.Widget(`#${this.props.id}`);
```

Any way, using of ref is better.

And thank you! I updated https://github.com/uploadcare/uploadcare-widget-react-demo/